# Is conditional expectation given a function of random variable well defined?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space and $X: \Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a random variable. Define another random variable $Y = h(X)$, where $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a $\mathcal{B}^1/\mathcal{B}^1$ measurable function. Suppose that $\mathbb{E}[X]$ exists and is finite. My question is, is $\mathbb{E}[X|Y] = \mathbb{E}[X|h(X)]$ always exists no matter what $h(\cdot)$ is? Or does it only exist whenever $h(\cdot)$ is a bijective function?

Comment: All that matters is $\sigma(Y)$ which is well-defined. When $h$ is injective, you get $E(X|Y)=h^{-1}(Y)$.

Comment: @A.S. Since the real function $h(\cdot)$ here is a measurable function, we know that $Y$ is also measurable so that $\sigma(Y)$ is well-defined. But in this case, suppose $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ is well-defined, then $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ will be a function of $Y = h(X)$, let it be $k = g(Y) = \mathbb{E}[X|Y]$.   Then I don't quite understand what's the value of $g(y) = \mathbb{E}[X|Y = y] = \mathbb{E}[X|h(X) = y]$?

Comment: Intuitively speaking, restrict $X$ to all the $x$ that satisfy $h(x)=y$ (that is $h^{-1}(y)$) and average $X$ over this set. I'm not sure what the question is as $g(y)$ is just evaluating $g$ at $y$. $g(y)=g(h(h^{-1}(y)))$.

Comment: @A.S. I got it, so this basically means that as long as $h(\cdot)$ is a measurable function then $\mathbb{E}[X|h(X)]$ is always well-defined, is that true?

Comment: Yes - you can condition on ANY sigma-algebra. It's especially easy to think of when you are conditioning $X$ on a function of $X$ - which basically lumps certain values of $X$ together (that get mapped to the same number) to make them indistinguishable, so the "average" is your best guess.

Comment: @A.S. Intuitively that makes sense, and this is also consistent with the measure theory definition of the conditional expectation. Good explanation, thanks!